# Opening a filesystem object properties window from powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to open the properties dialog of a file or folder from powershell?

And if so, how would I do it?

Comment: I think you only need to add `Self` to the Invoke when using it with `$folder`, not also with `$file`. If used with `$file`, I get an error ("cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"). I'm on version 5 though, maybe there is a difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$o = new-object -com Shell.Application
$folder = $o.NameSpace("C:\path\to\file")
$file = $folder.ParseName("filename.txt")

# Folder:
$folder.Self.InvokeVerb("Properties")

# File:
$file.InvokeVerb("Properties")
```

[Further reading](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/26/use-powershell-to-work-with-windows-explorer/)