# Windows powershell

Tags: windows-7, powershell, automation

Is it possible with powershell to automate a task when a file is opened or closed? More specifically: if I right click on a file there is the "context menu", is it possible to run one of those items in the menu automatically when a file is opened and/or closed?

Comment: PowerShell would be a bad tool for this. Why would you want to use it for GUI interaction? Maybe consider using something like AutoIt instead?

Comment: You can also edit the context menu and change file associations to do pretty much anything, but it does require some familiarity with the registry editor.

Comment: Powershell can setup event listeners for file opening and closing. Here's some info on opening object properties: https://superuser.com/questions/1115393/opening-a-filesystem-object-properties-window-from-powershell/1115470#1115470

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, so let me rephrase your question in my own words so you can verify that we're talking about the same thing here.

To my understanding, you want to make it possible to have a context item in explorer, that if you right-click a file, select the entry, it will launch powershell with one of your scripts, and parse the filename of the file you selected as extra argument.

See this question to find out what you need in your Powershell script to get the file arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157554/how-to-handle-command-line-arguments-in-powershell (I'll give an example of code later in this answer)

Now, in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, under * you need to create a new set of keys for your context menu item.

Create the following folder structure:
*\MyScript\Command\Open

Name MyScript to anything you desire. It'll show up in the Context menu.

Give the default parameter for Open the full path to PowerShell, then the full path of your script followed by a -file %1 for file itself.

In your script, you can now use

```
param (
    [string]$file = ""
)
```

If you check if $file is empty, then you know no file was parsed.